# Where to add type annotations to curried functions?

Tags: f#

In F# interactive, I can find the type of sprintf.

```
>sprintf;;
val it : (Printf.StringFormat<'a> -> 'a) = <fun:clo@163>
```

I can find the type of sprintf curried with the first parameter, if the curried function is not generic.

```
> sprintf "%g";;
val it : (float -> string) = <fun:it@134-16>
```

But if it is generic, then I get the value restriction error.

```
> sprintf "%A";;
error FS0030: Value restriction. The value 'it' has been inferred to have generic type
val it : ('_a -> string)    
Either make the arguments to 'it' explicit or, if you do not intend for it to be generic, add a type annotation.
```

I can add a type annotation to get rid of the value restriction like this, specializing the function for a type, eg. DateTime.

```
>let f : (DateTime -> string) = sprintf "%A";;
val f : (DateTime -> string)
```

How can I add the type annotation without the binding? I've tried the following ...

```
>sprintf "%A" : (DateTime -> string);;
error FS0010: Unexpected symbol ':' in interaction. Expected incomplete structured construct at or before this point, ';', ';;' or other token.
```

This is a similar example but harder ...

```
>sprintf "%a";;
error FS0030: Value restriction. The value 'it' has been inferred to have generic type
val it : ((unit -> '_a -> string) -> '_a -> string)    
Either make the arguments to 'it' explicit or, if you do not intend for it to be generic, add a type annotation.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to enclose your expression in parenthesis:

```
open System;;
(sprintf "%A" : DateTime -> string);;

val it : (DateTime -> string) = <fun:it@2>
```

That way you can specify the type annotation without the binding.

Comment: You can also simplify the annotation a bit and specify only the `DateTime` part: `(sprintf "%A" : DateTime -> _)`. The compiler can still infer the return type.

Comment: Partial annotation works great. The harder example then becomes: (sprintf "%a" : (_ -> DateTime -> string) -> _ -> _).

Answer (score 1):

What is actually happening is that fsi binds the last thing you type to a variable called `it`.  It effectively does

```
let it = sprintf "%a";;
```

Type annotations would need to go on the left hand side of the `=` which you can't access.  The problem is that you need a concrete type to give to any variable (in this case `it`).  A workaround could be

```
(fun t:DateTime -> sprintf "%a" t)
```